# How to design Matlab API for C/C++

Tags: c++, matlab

I want to design a Matlab APi for the C++ Code I have written in Visual Studio.

I am using two function says:

```
Function1(float a, float b, float c)

Function1(float d, float e, float f)
```

These are the two functions I am using in main function.

But now I want to make the Matlab Api so that I can use these whole code in Matlab.

I am very new to these API thing, so I am not very sure about the terms I have used. But only thing I am sure about is that I want to use it in Matlab from C++.

Comment: @learnvst opposite of that: he wants to call C functions from MATLAB. Dup of another post. ;)

Comment: You question seems unclear. At one point it seems like you want to call Matlab code from C++, at another it seems like you want to call C++ code from Matlab.

Comment: I want to call C++ code in Matlab.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti while i agree that it is a duplicate of that code, for this person they may just be able to get away with making a C callable wrapper and using `loadlibrary`